# Looking for a special views exposed filter with pager and select list

Tags: 7, views, paging

i'm looking for an exposed views filter like it is implemented at the linked page.
[Example here](https://www.kicktipp.de/demo/tippuebersicht)

a) While click on "1.Spieltag" there is a select list.

b) Also there are pager arrows to scroll through 1.Spietag 2.Spieltag ect...

Is there a module or a widget i have missed till now, with which i can achieve the described functionallity? Any other idea how to achieve this?

Thanks Tom

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Ctools, Views and date to the latest version as well.
Here the view i recreated from scratch after having updated the modules:

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['expose']['items_per_page_label'] = 'Éléments par page';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['expose']['items_per_page_options_all'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['expose']['offset_label'] = 'Décalage';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
/* Champ: Contenu : Titre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node'] = 1;
/* Critère de tri: Contenu : Date de publication */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Contenu : Publié */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Contenu : Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'publi' => 'publi',
);
/* Filter criterion: Recherche : Termes de recherche */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['id'] = 'keys';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['table'] = 'search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['field'] = 'keys';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'keys_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['label'] = 'Termes de recherche';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['operator'] = 'keys_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['keys']['expose']['multiple'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Date : Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['id'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['field'] = 'date_filter';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['operator'] = '<=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['label'] = 'Par date :';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['operator'] = 'date_filter_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['identifier'] = 'datepicker';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['expose']['multiple'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['form_type'] = 'date_text';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_fields'] = array(
  'node.created' => 'node.created',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['date_filter']['date_method'] = 'AND';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'test';
$translatables['test'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('test'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Éléments par page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Décalage'),
  t('Termes de recherche'),
  t('Par date :'),
  t('Page'),
);
```